# Implemented XOR as a macro not working as expected

Tags: c, macros, xor

I have an input string as `CHAR cszReadBuffer[1000]` which `XOR` operation apply on it with a key as `CHAR cszReadKeyBuffer[10]`, actually I read `key` and `buffer` from two files that contains as following

**key file content :**

```
abcd
```

**input file content :**

```
aaaaaddddrrrttt
bbbbrfgergv
b
eeerwef
```

When I read both `key` and `buffer` size and content, they are absolutely true as following :

```
dwKeyFileLength(key length) is 4 byte
dwLastBitChunk(input-file length) is 40 byte
```

Also contents (`cszReadBuffer`, `cszReadKeyBuffer`) are as the same contents in **above** files.

Now, with bellow implementation, `XOR` encryption and decryption working correctly :

```
for(int i = 0;i < dwLastBitChunk;i++)
    cszReadBuffer[i] = cszReadBuffer[i] ^ cszReadKeyBuffer[i % dwKeyFileLength];
```

Encrypted output :

```
̀Ԃ؀စᘑᘕ椗k؁ဃ̅ငሄ桬椁ݫĆᔓȆ
```

Also I have another implementation as following `macro` :

```
#define   XOR(data, key) \
    LONG lKeySize = lstrlenA(key); \
    for(int i = 0;i < lstrlenA(data);i++) \
        data[i] = data[i] ^ key[i % lKeySize]; \
```

But when I using of `macro` instead :

```
XOR(cszReadBuffer, cszReadKeyBuffer)
```

(**Just for encryption**) it give me bellow output :

```
 aaaaddddrrrttt
bbbbrfgergv
b
eeerwef
```

I wonder why is this happens? Any suggestion?

Comment: Nothing leaps out as wrong; how are you passing the arguments to the macro?  (I've seen many things go wrong in macros when you don't wrap uses of the arguments in parens)...e.g., if you passed the `key` parameters as `1 + keyBuf`

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I passed `cszReadBuffer` and `cszReadKeyBuffer` as data and key without any changes.

Comment: @WeatherVane i tried that, but its not working

Comment: Please don't change the code after receiving an answer. Add the revised code as an edit. Rolled back.

Comment: How do you print the encrypted string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calculating `lstrlenA(data)` in every loop, but `data` is changing.

The first character of the input and the key is `'a'` so

```
'a' ^ 'a' ==> 0
```

and so the loop iterates once only. You must be using a previously set variable to print the encrypted string.

Calculate the string length outside the loop, as you did in the successful example.

Comment: i tried 
 `LONG lDataSize =  lstrlenA(data); \
 for(int i = 0;i < lDataSize;i++) \`   but it not worked!

Comment: In that case, please edit the question to contain the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi Saying ".. but not worked!" is not a useful description. Explain what it is that did not work. How exactly did it fail?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi Check this: https://ideone.com/uwCv6M It seems to me that the solution from Weather Vane is fine

Answer (score 0):

I got it ((**while decrypting**) it makes no difference that use `lstrlenA()` in `loop` or out of the `loop` because :

Because I read buffer from file and may exist `0` character in buffer, So when i using of `lstrlenA()` in `macro` or anywhere it give me wrong size (Probability being `0` in buffer), So I should use of buffer-size directly as  `lpNumberOfBytesRead` value (which indicate how many bytes read when I'm reading from file with `ReadFile()` function) in my `macro` And I add `datasize` parameter for this.

Also this problem is exist in my `key` buffer.

So it must pass `data` and `key` sizes to macro as following :

```
#define     XOR(data, dsize, key, keysize) \
    for(int i = 0;i < dsize;i++) \
        data[i] = data[i] ^ key[i % keysize]; \
```

So I used of `macro` like :

```
XOR(cszReadBuffer, lpNumberOfBytesRead, cszReadKeyBuffer, dwKeyFileLength)
```

in `XOR()` parameters, I shouldn't  use of `lstrlenA()` because there's probability being `0` in `buffer`. So I used of a `lpNumberOfBytesRead` sa direct buffer-size and my key as direct file-size.